# How to select names in oracle10g database?

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle10g

[image]

i want to search the name who having skills  in java and oracle

and i know the coding like

```
select name from table_name where skills like '%java%' or skills like '%oracle%';
```

but my problem is,In servlet How can i do this?

```
String skills=request.getParameter("skill");
```

my select query

```
select name from table_name where skill like '"++"';
```

Here i am confused ,
i tried like this

```
select name from table_name where skill like '"+%skills%+"';
```

but not working.

I am a webdeveloper very new to oracle ,please help me

I am using oracle10g

Comment: You shouldn't have this db schema. Create a table person_skill with person_id and skill_id. Don't put more than one value in one row column.

Comment: How are you executing those statements? Via JDBC Statement, Hibernate, Oracle ADF or some other way?

Comment: '"+skills+"', but how to use the % here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `REGEXP_LIKE`

```
SELECT name from TABLENAME where  
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (skills, '(Java|Oracle)');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String query = "select name from table_name";
    String skills = request.getParameter("skill");
    StringBuilder likePart = new StringBuilder("");
    boolean appendOrClause = false;
    String skillsArray[] = skills == null ? null : skills.split(",");

    if(skillsArray != null && skillsArray.length > 0 ){
        for(String skill : skillsArray){
            if(skill.trim().length() > 0){
                if(appendOrClause){
                    likePart.append(" OR skills like '%" + skill.trim() + "%'");
                } else {
                    likePart.append(" where skills like '%" + skill.trim() + "%'");
                }
                appendOrClause = true;
            }
        }
        if(likePart.toString().trim().length() > 0){
            query += likePart.toString();
        }
    }
    if(query.indexOf("like") > 0 ){
        // User have skills
        // Fire query to get User Name
    } else {
        // User doesn't have any skills
        // don't Fire any query
    }
```